# renderizar parte específica de uma página

Tags: python, web-scraping

Estou usando o código a seguir para renderizar uma página da internet:

```
import dryscrape

# set up a web scraping session
sess = dryscrape.Session(base_url = 'http://www.google.com.br')

# we don't need images
sess.set_attribute('auto_load_images', True)

# visit
sess.visit("/")

sess.render("google.png")
```

Mas, gostaria de renderizar apenas uma parte da página, por exemplo no site do google, gostaria de renderizar apenas o doodle(`<div id=dood class=cta>`)

Tentei substituit a última linha por:

```
sess.at_css('.cta').render("google.png")
```

Mas isso não é permitido. Alguém sabe alguma maneira?

Answer (score 1):

Se o *dryscrape* não foi uma exigência da solução você pode fazer uma combinação de requests ao google e tratamento de texto com regex.

A ideia é ler a página do google, achar (via regex) o endereço do doodle, montar a url final, fazer download do arquivo e salvar no disco:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from urllib2 import urlopen
import re


response = urlopen('http://www.google.com.br/').read()
m = re.search(
    r'background:url\(([^)]+)\).+id="hplogo"',
    response
)

final_url = 'http://www.google.com.br{}'.format(m.group(1))
print 'Downloading {}'.format(final_url)

image = urlopen(final_url).read()
with open('google.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(image)
```

*Você pode precisar ler o content-type da imagem antes de salvar no disco.*

Isso tem um risco, se o google mudar o layout da página, muito provavelmente sua regex não vai dar match, ai você teria que refaze-la.

Answer (score 1):

A solução do @drgarcia1986 é a que eu tentaria, mas se você faz questão de usar o [dryscrape] (motivado pelo fato de muitos doodles do Google serem animados e usarem Flash/HTML5?), uma opção seria você, de alguma forma, editar o HTML da página principal pra deixar só o doodle. Se você descobrir um jeito de fazer o [dryscrape] abrir um arquivo HTML que você gerou, você pode tentar algo usando o [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(codigo_html_do_google)
soup.body = soup.find(**{'class': 'cta'})
codigo_html_simplificado = str(soup.body)
```

(talvez você precise tomar cuidado pra não destruir outros elementos da página como scripts, mas a ideia geral é essa)